# mySQL thinks I'm the blank (anonymous) user even after I've logged in

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, authentication

Using mySQL, the database keeps thinking I'm ''@'localhost' even though I've already signed in as '(username)'@'localhost'.

It gets stranger:

I'm allowed to create databases called 'test', 'test_db', etc. and tables within them, but if I try to create a database with any other name, I get a:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'someDB'
```

I've already logged in as 'username'@'localhost'. Why does it think I'm ''@'localhost'?

Perhaps this is relevant?

```
mysql> select user(), current_user();
+------------------+----------------+
| user()           | current_user() |
+------------------+----------------+
|username@localhost| @localhost     |
+------------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This becomes increasingly annoying as I try to use SQL within Java. It seems as soon as I log in it forgets that I've logged in as (username).

I've read somewhat about how usernames and login names are different? Why is user() different from current_user()? I think these might be clues... Any advice, friends?

Comment: What's your command line for starting up the mysql monitor?

Comment: `-bash:(server):~ 254 $ mysql -u (username) -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.`

Comment: If the anonymous user for localhost exists then it will match every username first. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412339/cannot-log-in-with-created-user-in-mysql

Comment: @MarcB the mysql startup command was in my previous comment.

Comment: @VMai Interesting, thank you. However, I do not have root privileges to be able to dump the mysql database or delete the anonymous user. Any other suggestions?

Comment: As long as the anonymous user exists, that's the one that will be matched when you connect. You can try bypassing `'localhost'` anonymous user by specifying TCP protocol. Try adding `-h 127.0.0.1` option to the `mysql -u ...` command. (It's possible you will also encounter another anonymous user, but that will be a different user `''@'127.0.0.1'`. (A database user with sufficient privileges can `DROP` those annoying anonymous users.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw has better explanation and hints, what you can try. But you could try the dba admin to remove this user.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks, but the `-h` tag didn't work. I suppose I'll just ask my sysadmin to drop the anon user. I'm shocked that this exists, though. Wouldn't it be theoretically causing problems for all default mySQL installs?

Comment: @VMai 's comment should be the accepted answer, would you mind adding it as an answer?