# MySQL not working with Laravel

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

This may be a noob question.

But I have tried everything, purging and reinstalling trying to reconfigure and the works.

For some reason my root that was set without a password on localhost is denying me access

I have tried to reset the root password using the command line but to no avail.

Does anybody know how to get this error to be fixed?

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'devin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I am using linux and ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you set your `root` user to login without a password, this does not mean that user `devin` has been configured to login without a password.

Edit your `.my.cnf` file:

```
vi ~/.my.cnf
```

In the file which you see, hard code the password for user `devin`, save the file, then exit.

```
[client]
user=devin
password=your_password_goes_here
```

Then restart MySQL and `devin` should be able to login without using a password.

The following command should work to connect you to a database called `my_db`:

```
mysql --user=devin my_db
```

Comment: Perhaps I have done it wrong, but I still get an error after this 

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'devin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

The only difference now is that it says using password: YES

Comment: Are you sure you have the right password?  Can you connect from the command line?

Comment: This is the error from the command line, It is wierd that it does not connect

Comment: It isn't weird if you are using the wrong password.  Are you _certain_ that the credentials are correct?  Have you ever been able to login?

Comment: Yes, I did a fresh install just before posting to make sure they were right, I have also tried a number of my most common passwords

Comment: There could many reasons why you cannot login in, you will have to debug this yourself.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412339/cannot-log-in-with-created-user-in-mysql) is one article which might help you.